# I wanna make a dictionary has user_id's key & all excel data

Tags: python, django, excel, dictionary

I wanna make a dictionary has user_id's key & all excel data .
Excel is
[image: excel]

In views.py I wrote

```
def try_to_int(arg):
    try:
        return int(arg)
    except:
        return arg

def main():
    book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
    sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)

    data_dict = OrderedDict()
    tag_list = sheet3.row_values(0)[1:]
    for row_index in range(1, sheet3.nrows):
        row = sheet3.row_values(row_index)[1:]
        row = list(map(try_to_int, row))
        data_dict[row_index] = OrderedDict(zip(tag_list, row))

    print(data_dict)

main()
```

print(data_dict) is

```
OrderedDict([(1, OrderedDict([('', ''), ('Ton', ''), ('0014500ab9Cd', '')])), (2, OrderedDict([('', ''), ('Tom', ''), ('0014500ab9Cd', '')])), (3, OrderedDict([('', ''), ('Tom', 'A'), ('0014500ab9Cd', '')])
```

It is not my ideal result.
I wanna make a dictionary like

```
dicts = {
    0014500ab9Cd: {
        New York_A-a_under500: ○,
        New York_A-a_500-700: ○,
          ・・・・
        New York_A-e_under500: ○,
          ・・・・
        New York_C-b_upper700: ×,
    },
    0014500ab9Cd: {
       Chicago_A-a_under500: ○,
       Chicago_A-a_500-700: ○,
          ・・・・
    },
}
```

I do not have to get name data.How can I get my ideal dictionary?What should i write it?

rows is like

```
['', '16690', '0014500ab9Cd', 'Tom', '40', '', 'leader']['', '28818', '000000ywAub', 'Blear', '23', 'others']
```

Comment: You cannot have same key having two values in a dictionary. Which is what your ideal result shows up as.

Comment: You want to create a nested dictionary i.e. `dict['0014500ab9Cd'][<city_A>][cost?] = 1 or 0` or if you know you have the same cost buckets then you could also use a list to maintain the order.

Comment: @Chinny84 Yes,i wanna create a nested dictionary u wrote.I wanna write do so,but do not know hotw to do it.Could u write the codes in answer?

Comment: If you could print a couple of rows and put it in the question then that would be great and I (we) can take a look.

Comment: @Chinny84 I updated rows.If u know something,please help me.

Comment: The rows you have provided does not line up with what you have in your ideal (or even spread sheet). I am guessing those lines are the headers for each sheet? Can you give an example set of rows from each sheet.

Comment: Try using `pandas` rather than `xldr` I had better experience.